# How to filter buddypress activity by date?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I need to filter buddypress activity by date, like today or last week. I am using

```
<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) . '&action=activity_update&year=2017&monthnum=04&day=4' ) ) : ?>
```

but its not working. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the activities by the following hook.

```
function my_bp_activities_by_date( $retval ) {
    $retval['since'] = '2014-04-04'; // return only items recorded since this Y-m-d H:i:s date;

    return $retval;
}
add_filter( 'bp_after_has_activities_parse_args', 'my_bp_activities_by_date' );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. I have paste the code in "bp-custom.php" and change the date to yesterday but it is still returning all posts.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply,  I just have paste the code in functions.php. but still not luck. showing all posts since buddypress installed.

Comment: I am trying to restrict user so that no one can make more than 10 post in buddypress in a day. do you have any suggestions how can I accomplish this.